# Ocaml "Out of memory" exception; verbose mode says "Stack overflow in structural comparison"

Tags: crash, ocaml, out-of-memory

A very huge ocaml program from an alien source needs to be fixed.  One of the problem is that the program crashes at seemingly innocent line:

```
Hashtbl.mem loc_to_no loc
```

with "Out of memory" exception.  The thing is that there's surely enough memory out there and this line is executed just fine for other inputs and even earlier during the processing of the problem one.

Having run it with `OCAMLRUNPARAM="v=63"`, I see a line that is printed right before crash:

> Stack overflow in structural comparison

The structures involved are defined below.  `loc` is of type `location`.

```
type ('a, 'b, 'c) automaton = {
  aut_id : int ;               
  mutable start_location : (('a, 'b, 'c) location) option ;
  mutable end_location   : (('a, 'b, 'c) location) option ;
  mutable aut_attributes : 'a ;                            
}
and ('a, 'b, 'c) location = {                              
  loc_id : int ;
  mutable succs : ('c * ('a, 'b, 'c) location) list ;
  mutable preds : ('c * ('a, 'b, 'c) location) list ;
  automaton : ('a, 'b, 'c) automaton ;
  mutable loc_attributes : 'b ;
}
```

What should be done to make the code execute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the hash table lookup uses "`=`" (structural equality) to determine if a key is the same as what you are looking for. Structural equality requires deep-checking all the substructures and stuff. You have a complicated recursive data structure. Perhaps there is a cycle in the structure at some point, which would cause it to loop infinitely. In any case, think about how you want the hash table to tell if a key is the same as yours, and then you need to use that kind of equality instead of the default structural equality; use the `Hashtbl.Make` functor to define a hash table module that has a custom equality and/or hash function.

Comment: Yep, it works.  By default, Hashtbl uses `=` for comparision of keys, which is recursive.  I made a functor that uses `==` for that purpose, this operator not comparing recursively.

Comment: yes, you can use == (physical equality); but in that case make sure that the object you are passing in is the same object that was used originally as the key (and not just another object with the same structure)